# Python print one by one list and add count

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to print a list of objects 1 by one and at the same time print count next to them.

Add something to the code so

```
for i in items:
    print(i)
```

returns:

1. wool
2. honey

   etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function you are looking for is `enumerate`

```
for idx, val in enumerate(items, 1):
    print(idx + '. ' + val)
```

As suggested by Harvey, `enumerate` returns a tuple, but `str.join` only accepts `str` iterables. If you were iterating over an indexable object whose keys and values were all strings (e.g. a `str` to `str` `dict`), then the code

```
for idx_val_pair in enumerate(items, 1):
    print('. '.join(idx_val_pair))
```

would also work.

EDIT: If you're just starting out with Python (which I suppose is the case) then don't worry about the stuff down here, but if you want to keep performance consistence among PyPy and CPython (among others) string concatenation is better done with the `join` method. The "correct" version of the code above would be

```
for idx, val in enumerate(items, 1):
    print('. '.join([str(idx), str(val)])
```

Comment: Thanks for the correction, didn't even realize that.

Comment: You could add a third example which uses the tuple of index and value directly:  `for idx_val in enumerate(items, start=1): print('. '.join(idx_val))`

Answer (score 2):

`enumerate` gives you the index of the current item returned.

You can use it like this:

```
# enumerate items, but start counting at 1
for i, j in enumerate(items, 1):
  print("{0}. {1}".format(i, j))
```

Here's an example usage:

```
>>> items = ["wool", "honey", "string"]
>>> for i, j in enumerate(items, 1):
...   print("{0}. {1}".format(i, j))
... 
1. wool
2. honey
3. string
```

Comment: Use the start parameter of enumerate: `enumerate(items, start=1)`

Comment: @Harvey Very cool. I didn't know that existed!

Comment: Also, if you never actually use `i` and `j` separately, you could do `for ij in...` `....format(*ij))`

Comment: Not as readable, but still noted.

Answer (score 1):

```
for count, label in enumerate(ls, 1):
    print '%d. %s' % (count, label)
```

Will produce desired output.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
for j in range(len(items)):
    print("%d. %s" % (j+1, items[j]))
```

Comment: This is not pythonic.

Answer (score 0):

This is done in python  2.7 and above answers gives already a good solution. As a python beginner I would start with something as simple solution as this. Printing can always be in prettier format, but just to give an idea.

```
    ls = ['wool','honey','extra']
    count = 0
        for l in ls:
        count+=1
        print str(count)+ '. ' + l
```

OR like suggested enumerate seems to be the best option

```
    for count, names in enumerate(ls, start=1): #start =   can be removed
        print str(count)+ '. ' + names
```